# Probability of getting 2 cards with the same color

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, card-games

> You have two decks of cards: a 52 card deck (26 black, 26 red) and a 26 card deck (13 black, 13 red).
>
> 1. You randomly draw two cards and win if both are the same color. Which deck would you prefer?
> 2. What if the 26 card deck was randomly drawn from the 52 card deck? Which deck would you prefer then?

The first question is straightforward. By symmetry,
$$P(\text{same color}) = 2P(\text{two red}) = 2P(\text{second red}|\text{first red})P(\text{first red}).$$
In the 52 card deck, the probability is thus $2 \cdot\frac{25}{51}\frac 12 = \frac{25}{51}$
while in the 26 card deck, it is $2 \cdot \frac{12}{25}\frac 12 = \frac{12}{25}$, and since $\frac{25}{51}> \frac{12}{25}$ the first deck has higher winning odds.

For the second question, here's my approach. Let $R$ be a r.v. modelling the number of red cards in the smaller deck. $R$ follows a hypergeometric distribution:
$$P(R=r) = \frac{\binom{26}{r}\binom{26}{26-r}}{\binom{52}{26}},$$
thus
$$\begin{align}
P(\text{same color}) 
&= P(\text{two red})+P(\text{two black}) 
\\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{26} P(\text{second red}|\text{first red, }R=r)P(\text{first red}|R=r)P(R=r) + P(\text{second black}|\text{first black, }R=r)P(\text{first black}|R=r)P(R=r)
\\ 
&=\sum_{r=0}^{26} (\frac{r-1}{25} \frac{r}{26} + \frac{25-r}{25} \frac{r}{26})\frac{\binom{26-r}{r}) \binom{26}{26-r}}{\binom{52}{26}}
\\
&= \frac{2}{25\cdot 26} E[R(R-1)] = \frac{2}{25\cdot 26}(V[R]+E[R]^2-E[R]) = \frac{25}{51}
\end{align}
$$
This is the same probability as for the full deck ! I'm very surprised with this result, I'd like to see an intuitive explanation or a shorter proof that doesn't involve as many computations.

Comment: If you first pick $26$ cards out of $52$ and then pick two random cards out of those, it's the same as picking $26$ cards out of $52$ and then taking first two of them because all orderings of $26$ cards are equally likely.  Which in turn gives the same result as picking $2$ cards out of $52$ and then not picking $24$ others.

Comment: @Ennar This makes perfect sense !

Comment: Surely makes sense to me, although I felt it's a bit hand-wavy. However, all I think I'm saying is that $\binom{26}{2} = \frac{26!}{2!24!}$.

Comment: You can post this as an answer so that the question does not appear unanswered :)

Comment: @Al.G. you are right. I wasn't initially sure if what I wrote is what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

If you first pick $26$
cards out of $52$
and then pick two random cards out of those, it's the same as picking $26$
cards out of $52$
and then taking first two of them because all orderings of $26$
cards are equally likely. Which in turn gives the same result as picking $2$
cards out of $52$
and then not picking $24$
others.